# jsk-ros-pkg "configuring incomplete" errors occured

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing jsk_common, which included the install of jsk_recognition and jsk_libfreenect2, did a source ~/ros/hydro/devel/setup.bash, complied by executing catkin_make in the catkin work folder ~/ros/hyro. After considerable script activity, following error message appeared.

```
[roseus.cmake] compile installed package sound_play
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'jsk_2014_06_pr2_drcbox'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_demos/jsk_2014_06_pr2_drcbox)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'jsk_rosjava_messages'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_smart_apps/jsk_rosjava_messages)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed.
```

No other error messages. Is there a log file to review for more detail?

openjdk-6-jre and openjdk-7-jre are installed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192512/jsk-ros-pkg-%22configuring-incomplete%22-errors-occured/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly did you do around "After considerable script activity`, in particular what was the last command you ran?

Also, many of `jsk-*` packages are actively maintained and available as DEB. Installable by `apt-get install ros-hydro-jsk-common` for example.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2014-09-11**:
Hi. 1) Installed "jsk_common" with the command "wget -q -o /tmp/jsk.rosbuild https://...". as listed in the "github/jsk-ros-pkg/  jsk_common" README.md, 2) in "~/ros/hydro/" folder, catkin_make.

I'll try install jsk-common and jsk_recognition from DEB.
Ross

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2014-09-11**:
Just installed ros-hydro-jsk-common & jsk-recognition into hydro/opt/share, but there is no DEB "ros-hydro-jsk-freenect2" pkg, What package shud I install equivalent to the jsk-libfreenect2?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-11**:
`jsk_freenect2` looks like not included in DEB yet. I asked on its [dev repository](https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_recognition/issues/287).